# Problems with GDAL, Libspatialite, Rasterio and Sumo (ImportError, Symbol _GEOSArea not found, Referencing from libspatialite.7.dylib)

Tags: gdal, rasterio, spatialite, geos, osgeo

I'm new to using gdal/libspatialite/rasterio/sumo and all the family of library and packages that is related to geographical, time and space. But I was just wondering what's this error here? Does anyone have experience with this error before? Have you seen it before? And if so have you been able to resolve it? And if so, what were the things you did to resolve it. I'm stuck with this for almost days now and idk what else to do. I'm running this on Python 3.9.6 on a MacOS Big Sur. I'm confused whether the problem is either one of these packages (or a combination of).

It's really annoying how it doesn't work here but works perfectly fine in my old computer that runs in MacOS Catalina with Python 3.9.0. Thank you in advance for your time.

```
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/contextily/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .place import Place, plot_map
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/contextily/place.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .tile import howmany, bounds2raster, bounds2img, _sm2ll, _calculate_zoom
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/contextily/tile.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rasterio as rio
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import gdal_version
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/_base.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _GEOSArea
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using the new M1 iMac, so could that be a possible reason?